# call Datatable ajax call on custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have used Server-side processing
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

```
   var table = $("#job-table").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: "<?php echo url('/getJobs');?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "connection": connectionArray,
                    "company": companyArray,
                    "type": typeArray
                }
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "job_id" },
                { "data": "type" },
                { "data": "connection_id" },
                { "data": "company_id" },
                { "data": "message" },
                { "data": "total_completion_time" },
                { "data": "date" },
                { "data": "start_time" },
                { "data": "end_time" },
                { "data": "error_time" }
            ]
        });
```

I want to call the same datatable ajax call after custom button click.
On this custom button I have changed the datatable ajax call parameters.
Is there any way to call the same ajax call? please help me here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Init datatable on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var CustomData = 'Value';
    oTable = $('#All_lists').DataTable({
        iDisplayLength:25,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": 'your_url',
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.key1 = CustomData,
                d.key2 = "Value2" 
            }
        },  
        columns: [
            {data: '0', name: 'branchlists.status'},
            {data: '1', name: 'branchlists.code'},
            {data: '2', name: 'fromBranch.name'},
            {data: '3', name: 'toBranch.name'},
            {data: '4', name: 'branchlists.total_receiept'},
            {data: '5', name: 'branchlists.total_parcels'},
            {data: '6', name: 'branchlists.total_weight'},
            {data: '7', name: 'branchlists.total_amt'},
            {data: '8', name: 'trips.vehicle_id'},
            {data: '9', name: 'print'}
        ],
    });
})
```

Change value of variable

```
CustomData = "ChangedValue";
```

After changing variable you need to reload datatable by calling below function anywhere

```
oTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: how can we use datatable ajax response data outside?
I want to use one response parameter and set it to span!

Comment: I guess you can use datatable init callback function. [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

Comment: @Progi1990, Did you find solution with callback function?

Comment: not yet! :( thought I have tried with success method inside datatable but it seems to not working there ... I can consoled the value or I can get it in success method but datatable shows processing

using drawCallback function I have get only table data not the parameters which I have sent in response!

Comment: You get what you wanted, AJAX response of datatable.

What else you need?

Comment: I call added new API, no I am calling two different API instead of calling single API :(

Comment: how it would be possible to call multiple APIs in datatable?

Comment: I mean I have written separate ajax call for second API!